# How to get my div outside wrapper, but text inside?

Tags: html, css

Like this:
[image]
I'm trying to make the blue text where it says join our discord server in width 100% when its inside wrapper, It's inside wrapper to get the text to match up with the wrapper

Comment: I didn't understand anything.

Comment: My div is inside wrapper, I want the div to be 100% width while the content inside the div is following the wrapper

Answer (score 1):

You apply a `background-color` to the full-width element, then wrap the inner text that you want contained in another element that matches whatever the width of your content section is. Here's an example to match your screenshot. `.viewport` will be the class that defines the width of the actual content - just nest that inside of elements that you want to be full-width.

```css
.container {
  background: #09c;
  color: #fff;
}

.viewport {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em 0 0;
}

.content .viewport {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="viewport">Join our discord server</div>
</div>

<nav class="viewport">navigation</nav>

<div class="content">
  <div class="viewport">content section<br>content section</div>
</div>
```